# Google Chrome Plugin Problems

Tags: google-chrome-extension, onesignal

Hello i am using onesignal however while i was adding it to my addition It goes wrong

Error: 'browser_action' is only allowed for extensions, but this is a packaged app.

'tabs' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app.

Code :

```js
{
 "name": "ZeoNNN Stream",
  "version": "1.02",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "zeoNNN.",

  "icons" : {
    "16"  : "icon-16.png",
    "48"  : "icon-48.png",
    "128" : "icon-128.png"
  },

    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup" : "hakkindapencere.html"
  },
 "app": {
      "background": {
        "persistent": false,
      "scripts": ["OneSignal.js", "background.js"] }
    },

  "permissions": ["gcm", "tabs", "storage", "notifications", "identity", "browser"]

}
```

Comment: This error is pretty spot on, you are using a browser action, but you populated the "app" field in the manifest, which is for packaged apps.  The browser action is for chrome extensions, not packaged apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove "tabs" from your permissions list and remove the use of browser_action. OneSignal does not require the "tabs" permission or use browser_action. Please follow the [OneSignal Chrome App/Extensions](http://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/chrome-app-sdk-overview) guide to setup push notifications in your Chrome App.